# SVN configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-dav-svn

My apache2 config for SVN:

> ServerName server.org

```
    <Location />

            DAV svn
            SVNPath /opt/svn/project.com

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Subversion Repository"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

            Require valid-user
    </Location>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
```

```
svnadmin create /opt/svn/project.com
svn import /var/www/project.com file:///opt/svn/project.com/
```

And now I want to be able to have three copies of my project from /opt/svn/project.com:

```
/var/www/test1.project.com
/var/www/test2.project.com
/var/www/test3.project.com
```

And I want to be able to commit this way:

```
cd /opt/svn/project.com
svn add ./auth/
svn co ./ -c 'Comment'
```

And I want to be able to update it on other hosts:

```
cd /var/www/test2.project.com
svn up ./
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a single authorization-enable repository, check it out to multiple locations, and work with it from any of those locations. This is pretty straightforward, and you should have no issues once you get your setup completed.

I think the following recommendations would ensure that you can do what you want, assuming that I am interpreting your question correctly.

1) Your Apache `Location` configuration should be as follows:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /opt/svn

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This will allow you to access your multiple check-out points without conflict with your repository. Like anything else on your web server, the URLs cannot conflict, so you shouldn't make the repository root the same as the web server root (`/`).

Also, I changed your `SVNPath` value - this is supposed to be the directory where your repositories live, not the path to one of the repositories itself.

2) Create the appropriate structures. Your `svnadmin create` is correct. However, to ensure flexibility in future development, you need to create the `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` directories under a project directory using `svn --parents mkdir`. Your resulting repository (accessed at the URL `http://server/svn/project.com/`) should have something like the following structure:

```
projectName
  branches
  tags
  trunk
```

The `trunk` is where you do all your work. The `branches` tree is for forking or parallel development, and the `tags` tree is for static snapshots of your code. You really only need `trunk`, as that's the one you'll be checking out in your example.

3) Only Subversion modifies the `/opt/svn/project.com` tree to add/modify content. Because of that, you can only commit on a checkout, not the way you indicated.

If you have a file system with your intended content, you can either:

- Check out the trunk and add your content under that:

  `svn co http://server/svn/project.com/projectName/trunk/ /var/www/test1.project.com`

  `cp /var/www/project.com/foo /var/www/test1.project.com`

  `svn add /var/www/test1.project.com/foo`

  `svn ci /var/www/test1.project.com`
- Or import into the repository:

  `svn import /var/www/project.com http://server/svn/project.com/projectName/trunk`

4) To get multiple working copies, just check out the `trunk` (or an appropriate subdirectory) to each of your specified locations. Then any modifications committed in one checkout can be retrieved as you indicated using `svn up`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ive configured all as you said. But when I'm trying to checkout my repo from another server I'm getting:


$ svn checkout https://project.com/svn/
svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'https://project.com/var/www/svn/'; please relocate

where /var/www =  DocumentRoot in Apache2.

If I'm not setting DocumentRoot at all then I'm getting relocate to htdocs :( What do I need to do?!

Comment: I think that there is still some confusion. The Subversion repository URL has to end with the directory you want a local copy of. Also, you should not check out to any directory in `/opt/svn`.

Can you provide full paths and (mostly) real examples? Also can you provide any more detail on the error message you received (you can use back-ticks to highlight the message).